# In mod rewrite ignore Dynamic Path and keep sub path

Tags: php, mysql, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a site with dynamic paths and I need to know how to keep a part or ignore it:

A couple examples of dynamic paths:

```
http://www.example.com/185/seo-dynamic-field.html
http://www.example.com/186/seo-dynamic-field2.html
```

As you can see seo-dynamic-field.html is a field generated from mysql and is only used for friendly url.
the id (`185` & `186`) is the real one that process the real query string which is:

```
RewriteRule ^/*(([^/]+)(.html))$ index.php?id=$2 [L]
```

This is working:

```
http://www.example.com/186.html
```

but what I want to do is the following:

```
http://www.example.com/186/seo-field.html
```

is there a way to just ignore the 2nd dynamic part of the path (seo-field1.html, seo-field2.html)???

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the current rewrite rule works for your first case???

Comment: I just corrected and removed the id from the RewriteRule to avoid confusing the people. Any ideas?

Comment: Just gave you an answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work...

```
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)/?.*\.html$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Here is the regex explained...

```
^/?(\d+)/?.*\.html$
```

```
Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match the character “/” literally «/?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d+)»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “/” literally «/?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Match any single character «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the characters “html” literally «html»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Comment: Nice explanation, it wors like a charm though.